# CSS alternative to li:has(+ .class) relational pseudo class and li:not(.class ~ li)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a script ([JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j55j7oos/2/)) that detects when an `li` block element is vertically centered on a page and assigns it a `.centered` class to make it bigger via CSS.

```
.centered {
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: #bbb;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
}
```

Once the central element is identified I manage to select the next sibling to via this:

```
.centered + li {
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
}
```

**The problem arises when I try to select the sibling element preceding the .centered element in pure CSS**

After looking at [this question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) I tried playing with the :has() pseudo class suggested in one of the comments and other selectors, but with no luck.

This CSS4 relational pseudo class could have done the trick, but is not currently supported:

```
li:has(+ .centered) {
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: #Fcc;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
}
```

I also tried to select the `last-of-type` of `li` elements that are not siblings of `.centered`, but either `:not()` supports only simple selectors or I'm just not getting how to chain the selectors properly.

Here's the non-working selector:

```
li:not(.centered ~ li):last-of-type {
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: #Fcc;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
}
```

**QUESTION: Is there any combination of pseudo classes and selectors that could do the trick in pure CSS?**

My hope is that some progress has been made since those questions have been asked.

Comment: That `**` font is really distracting.

Comment: The answer is no. Just give up and assign a unique class to the preceding `li` in your Javascript routine.

Comment: You're trying to go "backwards" in CSS and have one element affect the styling of something that occurs earlier. Can't do that.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for your comment, it made me realise that I could start my jQuery selection from the element preceding the middle one and then select downwards in CSS with `.top + li` and `.top + li + li`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3t4r8xy1/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any combination of pseudo classes and selectors that could do the trick in pure CSS?

There isn't; the reason `:not(.centered ~ li)` doesn't work is indeed that it only currently supports simple selectors — like `:has()`, `:not()` will only accept combinators in Selectors 4. Since there are no pseudo-classes that currently accept combinators, and the only available sibling combinators go forward, you are left with a very restricted domain language in this regard. This is why those additions to Selectors were made.

As for progress... progress on the `:has()` pseudo-class has been eh. Last I heard, the working group was still deciding between allowing a subset of `:has()` in CSS or separating that out into its own pseudo-class, and vendors were going to see how much of it they could implement in CSS for this to work. But I don't think there has been any data yet.

Answer (score 0):

Following the confirmation that it is impossible by @BoltClock and the @torazaburo comment I changed my initial jQuery selection starting element

From this:

```
        middleElement = this;
        $(this).toggleClass("centered", true);
```

To this:

```
        middleElement = this;
        $(this).prev().toggleClass("top", true);
```

Without adding extra javascript code, I could then change my CSS selectors.

From:

```
.centered { /*selects the middle element */ 
        height: 30vh;
        background-color: #bbb;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    }

.centered + li { /*selects the next sibling after middle element */ 
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    }

li:has(+ .centered){ /*not supported at time of writing*/
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: #Fcc;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    }
```

To:

```
 .top, .top + li + li { /* selects the siblings before and after the middle one*/
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    }


 .top + li { /* This selects the middle element*/
        height: 30vh;
        background-color: #bbb;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
    }
```

[>> JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t4r8xy1/3/)